# Is there a better way to break a list into columns?

Tags: html, css, list, bootstrap-5, html-lists

I try to break my list into 4 columns, using bootstrap i use grid and it feels illegal to do it in that way, is there a better way

This is what i did:

```
<div class="grid">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <li class="list-group-item">1</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">2</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">3</li>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <li class="list-group-item">1</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">2f</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">3</li>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <li class="list-group-item">1</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">2</li>
                </div>
            <div class="col">                
                <li class="list-group-item">1</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">2</li>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want it to break without adding any div tags is there a way?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid anyway. `ul` can only have `li` as direct children. So ANY divs in your current `ul` should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS `columns` property for this:

```css
ul {
  columns: 4;
}
```

```css
ul {
  columns: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">2</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">3</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">2f</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">3</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">2</li>             
    <li class="list-group-item">1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Note that you can't have divs between list items, too.

EDIT: I've just noticed you wanted two items in each of the last two columns, so `columns` may not be what you want. But rather than using divs, if you know the number of list items you'll have, you could place the list items into a grid by targeting them with something like `nth-child`.